# I need to set the 'OR' condtion for last where clause but it is setting as AND how can change in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, filter, search, sql

SQL need to change **AND** condtion to **OR** in below code

```
public function getOrders()
    {
        $po_number = "%"."A"."%";
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            );
            $this->orders->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ["sop" => "amt_sales_order_payment"],
                'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
                ['po_number']
            )
            ->where('sop.po_number LIKE ?',$po_number);
            
            $this->orders->setOrder(
            'ext_order_id',
            'desc'
            );
            echo  $this->orders->getSelect()->__toString();
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```

I the po_number **OR** condtion need to apply how can i apply this.

**Current Query**

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `sop`.`po_number` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_order_payment` AS `sop` ON main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id WHERE (`main_table`.`customer_id` = '200') AND (`status` IN('canceled', 'closed', 'complete', 'fraud', 'holded', 'partially_shipped', 'payment_review', 'pending', 'processing', 'shipped')) AND (sop.po_number LIKE '%A%')
```

**Expecting Query**

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `sop`.`po_number` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_order_payment` AS `sop` ON main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id WHERE (`main_table`.`customer_id` = '200') AND (`status` IN('canceled', 'closed', 'complete', 'fraud', 'holded', 'partially_shipped', 'payment_review', 'pending', 'processing', 'shipped')) OR (sop.po_number LIKE '%A%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `->where('sop.po_number LIKE ?',$po_number);` with `->orWhere('sop.po_number LIKE ?',$po_number);`